# Button Event Issue using Jquery in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I need to know about using Jquery framework in Meteor.I did a simple example with using Jquery button event but get some errors.I didn't get any idea about this errors.So please see the below code and suggest me what to?

HTML Code :

```
app.html
--------

<head>
  <title>app</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  {{> menu}}
</body>

menu.html
---------

<template name="menu">

<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button>Click me</button>

</template>
```

JS Code :

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
 Template.menu.events
     ({
         $(document).ready(function()
        {
          $("button").click(function()
           {
             $("p").hide();
            });
        });
      });
    }
```

Error Message :

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
client/menu.js:5:7: Unexpected token (

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: 1) This is compilation error, 2) Don't manually load jquery - meteor includes it for you, 3) Don't use `$(document).ready` in a meteor app - replace this code with an event map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [meteor event maps documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) for examples of options for Template.menu.events().  Your click function could be written like this:

```
Template.menu.events({
  'click button': function(){
    $("p").hide();
  } 
});
```

If you need to use jquery to add an event, a better place is in your templates rendered function. Like this:

```
Template.menu.rendered = function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     $("p").hide();
  });
};
```

Comment: Okay Thank you its work fine but get error in web console.So Can you please check once the error :  `[19:10:05.567] Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/.`.@user728291